# Is there software to validate formal demonstrations?

Tags: logic, math-software, proof-theory

Anyone knows a software that compiles formally well-defined algebraic equations to validate their correctness?

For example, I insert a statemente in latex like that:

\forall S_i \in S \to \exists! R_i \mid R_i \subset  S \land S_i \notin R_i \land   |Ri| = k

It looks like ...

$$\forall S_i \in S \to \exists! R_i \mid R_i \subset  S \land S_i \notin R_i \land   |Ri| = k $$

and before compilation the software tells what errors encounter or if it is ok.

Comment: Maybe https://coq.inria.fr/

Comment: @Wraith1995 Dabuti ... smells good ;)

Comment: There are many automated theorem provers. Wikipedia has [a list of several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving#Comparison). Coq is a proof assistant, not an automated theorem prover. Wikipedia has [a list of several of those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant#Comparison) as well. With a proof assistant *you* build the proof, and it checks it. Most proof assistants have some degree of automation, but it is intended to be human guided. Automated theorem provers do all the work, but they can fail to find a proof in a timely manner at which point you're just stuck.

Comment: Your example is about set theory rather than equational logic. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @DerekElkins:your description of the user experience with a typical proof assistant is a little misleading. As you say, typical proof assistants have a lot of automation built in, so the user doesn't "build the proof" but gives the proof assistant a sequence of commands that tell it how to build the proof. Compare the tasks of operating a crane on a building site and doing the work that the crane does yourself.

Comment: ... and (while I'm dreaming up what I hope are useful analogies) fully automated theorem provers are a little bit like the machines locksmiths use to copy keys: they work well a lot of the time, but sometimes they don't, and then some expertise is required to get a copy that really works, and sometimes no amount of expertise will lead to a working copy.

Comment: Are you asking for grammatical correctness or propositional correctness?